# How to display contents of 'booktitle' field of a bibliographic entry?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Why am I not getting text written in `booktitle` for `Code snippet 1` when I am getting it for `Code snippet 2` ?. Both are included in the same `.bib` file.

Code snippet 1:

```
@book{article1,
    title={Comprehensive experimental analyses of automotive attack surfaces.},
    author={Checkoway, Stephen, McCoy and others},
    booktitle={USENIX Security Symposium},
    year={2011},
    organization={USENIX Security Symposium},
}
```

[image: Code Snippet 1]

Code snippet 2:

```
@inproceedings{article35,
    title={Securing vehicles against cyber attacks},
    author={Larson, Ulf E and Nilsson, Dennis K},
    booktitle={Proceedings of the 4th annual workshop on Cyber security and information intelligence research: developing strategies to meet the cyber security and information intelligence challenges ahead},
    pages={30},
    year={2008},
    organization={ACM}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Without seeing the code your are using to generate the bibliography, it will be difficult to help you.  `booktitle` is not a recognized field for the `article` type (which uses `journal` instead). Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: The formatting of bib entries is determined by the bibliography style that you chose. Which bibliography style are you working with?

Comment: @AlanMunn You were partially right. article does not recognize booktitle but its accepting journal as well

Comment: @mico I am using 'unrst' style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all bibliography styles I'm familiar with (including `unsrt`), the field `booktitle` is ignored for entries of type `@book`. The entry with key `article1` currently suffers from (at least) two errors. First, the entry type should almost certainly be either `@inproceedings` or `@incollection`, not `@book`. Second, there's an error in the `author` field. On must use the keyword `and`, not commas, to separate authors in the `author` field. Also, do provide not only a surname but also the given name(s) of the second author (McCoy). The faulty field `Checkoway, Stephen, McCoy` is (mis!)interpreted by BibTeX as denoting a single author with surname `Checkoway`, "Junior Component" `Stephen`, and first name component `McCoy`. Ouch! Don't do this.

Here's what I believe an improved entry. The bibtex information was obtained from https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2028073.

[image]

Observe that because you're using the rather ancient `unsrt` bibliography style (which hasn't been updated materially since the late 1980s), the contents of the `url` field are not shown. If you wanted to show the contents of `url` fields, you should load the `natbib` package and employ the `unsrtnat` bibliography style.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@inproceedings{Checkoway:2011,
  author    = {Checkoway, Stephen and McCoy, Damon and Kantor, Brian and Anderson, Danny and Shacham, Hovav and Savage, Stefan and Koscher, Karl and Czeskis, Alexei and Roesner, Franziska and Kohno, Tadayoshi},
  title     = {Comprehensive Experimental Analyses of Automotive Attack Surfaces},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 20th USENIX Conference on Security},
  series    = {SEC'11},
  year      = {2011},
  location  = {San Francisco, CA},
  pages     = {6--6},
  numpages  = {1},
  url       = {http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2028067.2028073},
  acmid     = {2028073},
  publisher = {USENIX Association},
  address   = {Berkeley, CA, USA},
} 
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much @Mico !!! 'incollection' solved my issue. I need one more help. i want to add publisher for journals but the 'article' is not supporting publisher field. Do you know what would be the best choice.

Comment: @PushpanjaliChauhan - It is indeed not common to list the publisher of an academic journal. If you do need to show this piece of information, I suggest you use the `note` field.